# MongoDB java - update into null array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm adding elements into an array("users") by using the $addToSet, but sometimes the array is null. Already tried to check if is null, and if it is use the $push, but I'm getting a *The field 'users' must be an array but is of type null in document*.
Any ideas? This is the code I'm using:

```
    if(!userIsAssociated(campaign,user)){
    collection.updateOne(
            Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId(id)),
            Updates.push("users", user));
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide code for `users` array?

Comment: It's an array of strings. The problem is when user: null

Comment: correction: users:null

Comment: This will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770550/push-object-into-array-if-the-array-exists-otherwise-create-the-array-with-objec