# Mongodb not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection `Trips` and I want to be able to add a passenger to the passenger array or create an array with a passenger. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770960/3462319) mentions `$push` but even though node logs `reserved seat on the trip` and the front end has an alert with `Your seat has been reserved` the collection isn't updated (there is no passenger array in the Trips collection).

```
//reserve a seat for a trip
app.post('/api/trips/:trip/:passenger',function(req,res){
    console.log('trip:'+req.params.trip)
    console.log('passenger:'+req.params.passenger)
    db.collection('Trips').update({'_id':req.params.trip},{ $push: { "passengers": req.params.passenger }},function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err

        console.log('reserved seat on the trip')
    })
    res.send('Your seat has been reserved')

})
```

Mongo 3.2.11

Node 9.4.0

Express 4.15.5

Is there something wrong with my MongoDB call? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Convert your string to objectID. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076460/how-to-convert-a-string-to-objectid-in-nodejs-mongodb-native-driver/21076589)

Comment: I was referring to _id. Is your _id a hex string ?

Comment: yes the _id is a hex string and corresponds to the _id of a document. Wouldn't it throw an err if it needed to be an objectID and wasn't?

Comment: No it wont. you have to take care of passing correct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Veeram comments you need to pass the correct type, in this case `ObjectId`.

The correct code looks like:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

//reserve a seat for a trip
app.post('/api/trips/:trip/:passenger',function(req,res){
    console.log('trip:'+req.params.trip)
    console.log('passenger:'+req.params.passenger)
    db.collection('Trips').update({'_id':ObjectId(req.params.trip)},{ $push: { "passengers": req.params.passenger }},function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err

        console.log('reserved seat on the trip')
    })
    res.send('Your seat has been reserved')

})
```

Comment: Please accept your answer to let people know that this the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on a project which involves node.js and mongodb.
The best way I have seen so far to post/get data from database is using mongoose.

This is the post part of my server.js file.

```
app.post('/description', (req, res) => {

  var DescriptionModel = new descriptionModel({
    header: req.body.header,
    header_image: req.body.header_image,
    sub_heading: req.body.sub_heading,
    sub_heading_tagline: req.body.sub_heading_tagline,
    sub_heading_image_path: req.body.sub_heading_image_path,
    sub_heading_data: req.body.sub_heading_data,
    paralax_image_heading: req.body.paralax_image_heading,
    paralax_image_tagline: req.body.paralax_image_tagline,
    gallary_heading: req.body.gallary_heading,
    gallary_tagline: req.body.gallary_tagline,
    gallary_image_path: req.body.gallary_image_path
  });

  DescriptionModel.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  })
});
```

I am taking data from the post html body, you can directly enter your data.

I have created a schema file which I have imported.

If you need more help please ask in comments, I'll be happy to explain in more detail.